# How to sum multiple rows in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset of 2.5M entries.  Trying to do something fairly basic on that data just adding all rows of the same time.  I have tried SUM and dcast but I'm not sure it is doing what I want.

```
date,time,available,free,total
d1,t1,1,2,3
d1,t1,2,3,4
d1,t1,3,4,5
d1,d2,2,3,4
d1,d3,4,3,2
d2,t1,2,3,4
...
```

I want to sum all the available, free and total figures for each d&t distinct date and time

Tried things like `info <- dcast(availwet, scrappedDate + scrappedTime ~ ., sum)`
but that only works if I change the data to have one of available, free or total in the df.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a big dataset, I would use either `data.table` or `dplyr` methods.

Using `data.table`, we convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'date' and 'time' column, we loop through the remaining column with `lapply` and get the `sum`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[,lapply(.SD, sum) ,.(date, time)]
```

Or a similar option using `dplyr`, we group with the grouping columns and use `summarise_each` to get the `sum` of the remaining columns.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(date, time) %>%
   summarise_each(funs(sum))
```

Or the `formula` method with `aggregate` (a `base R` option suggested by @David Arenburg).  We place the grouping columns on the RHS of `~` and on the LHS we can simply use `.` to signify the rest of the columns.  It is a convenient function though it might be slower for big datasets.

```
aggregate(.~ date + time, df1, FUN= sum)
```

Comment: `aggregate(.~ date + time, df1, sum)` too, no? (haven't tested)